# StencilJS build failed after version upgrade

Tags: build, compiler-errors, stenciljs, stencil-component, stencil-compiler

I have an issue with build stencil app after version upgrade.
I had @stencil/core version - 2.17
After `yarn add @stencil/core@3`  it builds and works correctly without any changes.
I want to upgrade Stencil's version to 4.

But after `yarn add @stencil/core@4` and adding to `tsconfig.json` `"verbatimModuleSyntax": true` instead of `"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"` I have build failed after `stencil build` without any error messages:

```
[06:08.0]  @stencil/core
[06:08.5]  v4.3.0
[06:13.4]  build, search, prod mode, started ...
[06:13.6]  transpile started ...
[06:20.7]  transpile finished in 7.10 s

[ ERROR ]  build error

[06:20.7]  build failed in 7.29 s
```

`stencil build -verbose` also not shows any messages about error.

How I can check what I should to fix for normal build?

Comment: Did you consult the upgrade docs? https://stenciljs.com/docs/introduction/upgrading-to-stencil-four

Comment: yes, it not helps

Comment: Could you open an issue on the stencil repository? The team would be love to take a look!